# Trying to trigger a safe transaction by another safe that is a signer on that safe

Tags: gnosis, gnosis-safe

I am trying to trigger a multisend transaction on a safe from another safe.

The signer below is a signer on safeOne. safeOne is a signer on safeTwo.

I would like safeOne to trigger the transaction on safeTwo. Right now the transaction is completely bypassing safeOne =( . It is being trigged by signer instead of safeOne.

Thanks for your help, frens.

```
  const provider = getDefaultProvider(process.env.INFURA_RINKEBY_URL);
  const signer = new Wallet(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY, provider);
  const ethAdapter = new EthersAdapter({ ethers, signer });
  const getGasPrice = provider.getGasPrice();

  const safeSdk = await EthersSafe.create({
    ethAdapter,
    safeAddress: safeOne,
  });

  const safeSdk2 = await EthersSafe.create({
    ethAdapter,
    safeAddress: safeTwo,
  });



  const txOptions = {
    gasPrice: getGasPrice,
    gasLimit: 8450000,
  };


  const safeTransaction = await safeSdk.createTransaction(
    multiSendTx,
    txOptions
  );


  const executeTxResponse = await safeSdk2.executeTransaction(safeTransaction);

  const receipt = await executeTxResponse.transactionResponse?.wait();

  console.log(receipt.transactionHash);
```

Comment: Hey, this is not natively supported by the sdk. You need to create a transaction that triggers the [execTransaction](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-contracts/blob/1.3.0-libs.0/contracts/GnosisSafe.sol#L111) of your second Safe. To make this easier I opened https://github.com/gnosis/safe-core-sdk/issues/131. I will try to draft an example how to do this with the current sdk functions, but not sure if I get to it before Christmas.

Comment: @Richard Hey Richard, thanks very much for opening that issue. Looking forward to seeing it in action with the current sdk functions and then the eventual native support. Happy Holidays.